# Why was Harley recruited into the squad?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad, suicide-squad-2016

I understand that the other characters in the squad have a relatively controllable personality or at least possess a useful ability that make them an asset worth the trouble of containing them.

- Deadshot: relatively stable and an amazing marksman
- Captain Boomerang: world-class thief and at least capable of mid-range combat
- Killer Croc: uncontrollable but is built like a tank and can breathe underwater
- Diablo: Non-violent and hosting a demi-god
- June Moone: Also contains a demi-god and is perfectly stable when she's in proper control of her powers
- Slipknot (technically): Can climb really fast and is a good extra to kill off to increase tension

The problem is that Harley seems to be outclassed and more uncontrollable than any of them. She's not superpowered, she's (in Amanda Waller's own words) more psychotic than The Joker, she doesn't have any real combat abilities, and at best she's got a decent batting arm and six bullets in a standard revolver.

Why was it so important that Harley be included in the mission?

Comment: Plain and simple fanservice.

Comment: None of them really seem capable of dealing with the Superman-level threat that Waller gives as the reason for forming the squad. Only Diablo and June Moone would really be any use against a villain at that level.

Comment: @Torisuda Give Deadshot a meat shield (like Diablo) and kryptonite bullets and he can probably take out Superman.

Comment: @DariM True. And Deadshot does seem more obviously useful against a wide range of threats than Harley or Captain Boomerang.

Comment: @DariM To be fair, if The Lesser Captain had thrown more than four boomerangs in the entire movie, one of which was in a flashback, he might have done better.

Comment: "Captain Boomerang" ---> dual wielding knives. Makes perfect sense.

Comment: “she doesn't have any real combat abilities” — er, she seemed to fight and shoot just fine.

Comment: read the new 52 (which is where the squad lineup seems to come from in the movie).  There are a lot of lesser known villains that float in and out of the group as well as some big names.  getting in the the squad is more about being in the wrong place at the wrong time then hand picking assets.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The premise of "Harley quinn is not superpowered ..... she doesn't have any real combat abilities" is wrong.

Harley Quinn is made to show athleticism, combat skills, and murderous determination. She saves Rick Flag at least once, and holds her own against the minions. She becomes a bit useless against the big bad by herself, but then practically everyone is just focusing on not being hit there.

Also remember the name of the team - Suicide Squad. Just like everyone else, Harley is an expendable asset. If she happens to perish or be tasked with something that will result in her death, that's enough use out of her for Amanda Waller and Rick Flag.

Comment: Harley is also pretty devious, and her insanity makes her unpredictable, which could be useful in a more nuanced scenario than the straight up firefight that we saw in the movie.

Comment: >! Don't forget that she is really useful in the end because of her uncontrollability.